# How to add equation number?

Tags: equations

```
\[L_{AABB}=-logI_o\cup(\hat{R},R^\star)=-log\frac{\mid\hat{R}\cap{R^\star}\mid}{\mid\hat{R}\cup{R^\star}\mid}\]\label{one}\]
```

how to add equation number?

Comment: Use `equation` environment.

Comment: Off-topic: Don't use `\mid` in the present context; instead, use `\vert`, or just type `|`. The whitespace inserted around the `\mid`-vertical bars is typographically inappropriate.

Comment: also use `\log` not `log`